# How to make redis pod auto-delete when list is empty

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I want to deploy redis pod which loads a list. Then I will have kubernetes job which will execute bash script with variable taken from that list in redis.

How can I make this redis pod to be auto deleted when all items from a list are used?

Comment: I'd guess a sidecar that deletes itself using a Role assigned to its ServiceAccount, or the opposite by having the k8s Job delete the redis Pod when it has finished (kind of a pull versus push distinction). The devil's in the details with that kind of stuff, but your question has very little specifics causing you to get very little specifics in a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Kubernetes keeps the completed jobs and associated objects for debugging purposes, and you will lose all the generated logs by them when deleted.

That being said, a job can be automatically deleted by using the [TTL mechanism for finished Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs).

Here you can find an example of a job's manifest with the TTL enabled and set to delete the job and associated objects (pods, services, etc.) 100 sec after its completion:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi-with-ttl
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bash script which is checking a list, if it is empty it kills a redis-server. That means pod is finished and with ttlSecondsAfterFinished job will be deleted

```
#!/bin/sh

list=$(/usr/local/bin/redis-cli -h $HOSTNAME lrange dealer_codes -1 0)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  /usr/local/bin/redis-cli -h $HOSTNAME shutdown
fi
```